# Coding with background images

Tags: html, css

Currently i have a running slideshow as my website background (3 images)

I also have a logo in the middle of these 3 images, which remains there throughout the duration of the slideshow.

Whilst the first image is displayed (when the website is loaded up) the logo image (which also has the function of a button) can be clicked and direct you to another website, however when the images change, the logo remains, however the ability to click is gone...

all help greatly appreciated

here is my current code

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var header = $('body');
  var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(http://urs2009.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/lights-of-city.jpg)', 'url(http://hdwallpaperd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/background-wallpaper-hd-1.jpg)', 'url(http://guruwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Sunset-Wide-Screen-Wallpapers-6.jpg)'
  );
  var current = 0;
  function nextBackground() {
    $('#mask').fadeTo(1000, 0.9, function() {
      current++;
      current = current % backgrounds.length;
      header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    })
    $('#mask').fadeTo(500, 0);
  }
  setInterval(nextBackground, 5000);
  header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-background-size: 1390px 700px;
  -moz-background-size: 1390px 700px;
  background-size: 1390px 700px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 600%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.GFImage {
  margin-top: 65px;
  border: 0;
}
.Footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  color: white;
  background: #151515;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 7%;
}
#mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <br>
  <h1>Welcome to GF</h1>
</center>
<center>
  <br>
  <h3>Welcome to GF! Check out all the information you need by just the click of a button...</h3>
</center>
<center>
  <a href="Home Page .html">
    <img src="Images/GF Logo White .jpg" style="width: 275px; height: 275px;" class="GFImage">
  </a>
</center>
<div class="Footer">
  <p>Copyright &COPY All Rights Reserved. Design by Gavin Foley.</p>
</div>
<div id="mask">SCRIPT FUNCTION IN HERE!!!!</div>
```

Comment: OP I've made a copy of your code into the snippet and seems to work fine. Chrome - Windows

Comment: yes, but for the second image, you cannot click the logo

Comment: I also can click the image!! I could't simulate the problem

Comment: I can click also on the three images

Comment: so you could get redirected, during all three images? constantly could click the GF logo?

Comment: @BISUCC Yes, I could click and redirect on all three images.

Comment: any reason why it may differ for myself?

Answer (score 1):

Seams like the link goes below the images.

I was able to solve this adding to the link element these properties:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:9
```

and then it should work.

**EDIT**

Just as a suggestion, have a look at this example, it could be useful if you are at the first try with html and css:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: so it now should read 

<a href = "jhskajh" position: absolute; z-index: 9;>?? sorry am new to this

Comment: yes, it worked fine for me. But bare in mind that the center tag is deprecated, as already mentioned above.

Comment: @BISUCC It would be: `<a href = "jhskajh" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9;" >` or you can add it to CSS: `a { position: absolute; z-index: 9; }` but note that the second way adds that to all `<a>` tags, which you probably don't want.

Comment: perfect thank you, however that now introduces the small problem of the logo never fading away haha